# Android YouTube Player won't auto play videos when ads are embedded

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have an app that basically relies on videos to auto-play, but the YouTube API won't let you auto-play if they randomly choose to inject an ad first in the video.

In more, I have a list of `YouTube` videos and `YouTubePlayer` in activity all videos autoplay turn by turn. it's working well. but now the problem occurs when I have added `AdMob` interstitial ads  on video starting. the ads display but when I close ads after the video in pause even I write code for play video in the ads close method.

So basically I want to play the video automatically without user tapping on it after ads close.

```
private YouTubePlayer player;
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_id));

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                player.play();
// player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (null == player) return;
        this.player = player;
        // Start buffering
        if (!wasRestored) {
           player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }

        // Add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });


        player.setPlaybackEventListener(new PlaybackEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
            }
        });
    }
```